# How to remove releases from Internal and Closed testing tracks in Google Play Console Dashboard

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, google-play-internal-testing

I uploaded version-4 of my app to the Internal test track of google play. When I found some bugs in this version, I updated my code and new release (version-5) to the Production track.

Now, the old version (version-4) is still seen in the Internal test track. Is there any option to remove this from the releases list in the internal test?

The same problem facing in Closed testing too...

Comment: it will just a part of the release history, more like archived. It won't be delivered to testers.